# Degree vs IQ test?

Tags: exams

Considering a for a high number of jobs, the degree you do is not directly related to what you do in your job.

Wouldn't it be a better idea simply to have some sort of national IQ test at 18 (or updated each year) and use this as a basis of selecting people for jobs.

As far as I can see, a degree is more like a 3 year endurance test. Of who is best at postponing financial gratification the longest.

I'm sure there is a big lobby in the University sector to send more people to University. But really, is there any point?

The Universities are left over from the time when boys were sent out to learn about Christianity and Latin and ancient greek philosophies. It had a quasi-religious component to it. (As Oxbridge still retains to some extent).

If we universities didn't exist, I'm not sure we would invent them as a way of selecting people for jobs.

So would an IQ test be better?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a rant, not a question.

Comment: IQ tests don't really tell you much beyond the ability to take IQ tests.

Comment: @Buffy Exactly the same could be said about degree exams.

Comment: Being good at pattern-matching is pointless if you have no idea what the terminology in a field means.

Comment: You are saying that it would better to decide one's aptitude for the rest of their life based on the results of one test at the age of 18 rather than through 4-5 years of continued development in undergrad with different forms of evaluation? Really?

Comment: @Cell Well you could retake the IQ test every year. Why not? Better than having it based on some exams you took when you were 21.

Comment: @Azor Ahai As I said in the question most people do a job not related to their degree. So those terminology would be useless.

Comment: @Buffy because 'smart' or 'IQ' are not really scientific terms, right? see [NNT](https://medium.com/incerto/iq-is-largely-a-pseudoscientific-swindle-f131c101ba39) aka [Nero](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/88078/), [Dweck](https://news.stanford.edu/pr/2007/pr-dweck-020707.html) and [salman khan](https://www.khanacademy.org/college-careers-more/talks-and-interviews/talks-and-interviews-unit/conversations-with-sal/a/the-learning-myth-why-ill-never-tell-my-son-hes-smart)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. An IQ-test does not tell much about the candidates and it does most likely not tell about the skills which one needs in a job. For work, being a good reliable worker with social skills is often more important than IQ.

Moreover, do you really propose that the state should tell the lower half of the people "hey you are too stupid, you will never get a job"? Wouldn't this turn your state into two social plateus, the lower one being a ghetto with high criminality? It would not talk long for a (violent) revolution unless you propose some strict dictatorship...

Comment: Not sure how this is any different to the state saying: "you are too stupid to pass your degree." You're falling into the trap of thinking that most people value IQ. This is not true. Many working class view high intelligence with suspicion. Instead they value kindness, strength and hard work as more important. Like the age old question "Would you rather be intelligent, strong or beautiful?" Not everyone would choose intelligent. Pretty sure most working class would look at the "brainiacs" with distain rather than jealousy. There would be jobs for strong people as well as high IQ people.

Comment: @zooby: So what do you suggest should the state do after vcollecting the IQ results?